how to change k8s api version?
I have set up AWS EKS cluster , my eks cluster version is 1.29 . I have install kubectl 1.29 . and follow all the command as per guidelines . when i run command  # kubectl get nodes . then its showing error = error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"
how to update this api version and what changes i have to do ?
in ./kube/config file I make some changes that = apiVersion : v1 and  v1beta2
apiVersion: v1
clusters:

cluster:
certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSURCVENDQWUyZ0F3SUJBZ0lJU3Q3bWhoNm53M3N3RFFZSktvWklodmNOQVFFTEJRQXdGVEVUTUJFR0ExVUUKQXhNS2EzVmlaWEp1WlhSbGN6QWVGdzB5TkRBMk1ETXdOREkwTWpkYUZ3MHpOREEyTURFd05ESTVNamRhTUJVeApFekFSQmdOVkJBTVRDbXQxWW1WeWJtVjBaWE13Z2dFaU1BMEdDU3FHU0liM0RRRUJBUVVBQTRJQkR3QXdnZ0VLCkFvSUJBUURORTFBdTVhZlAwUko1WTZMV215MXpxMmtEQ0hiZlhKMkRUaGdLMFAvVndtRTJMb2Z3OUoxaWM0U2YKZ094NWpDRjdwTjBsVzQxbVFNWTFHYVFLTU81dWVMNDFYcXpPNWZGamVJWFcrVUZxSDMzQnlJRnNWNHFYS3hJbQpnQldydmo3bjk3a3BwT3NyV0RxMENsdTBLc3lUZ2ZjMHhuSWFIa2VuWG9ZUTVYdzRrWHN6dU4vTDBmNlNTaW1QClltL0pTM1VCZmtSOUZ2QWxyTHFBa2lLQTlYUVVTTElkekpqa2JHQzErQk5LZHp0VFJjN2VZc0JiN01kV05Cd0EKWFd5UDc1Z1dubk1LdGhWUlFKSmIzb3FGV09jc0RHUVdqMHFxZ3FlQmpvOEM0Rm1uclg3cWlER29mSDQ0VWFDTgpyVitiWmoyWDZLV3prK2VSeGNERWJHR3FMRnk3QWdNQkFBR2pXVEJYTUE0R0ExVWREd0VCL3dRRUF3SUNwREFQCkJnTlZIUk1CQWY4RUJUQURBUUgvTUIwR0ExVWREZ1FXQkJUTnNEOEZyOUhQQmVyN3ZMc0dKcld6aWN3aVlqQVYKQmdOVkhSRUVEakFNZ2dwcmRXSmxjbTVsZEdWek1BMEdDU3FHU0liM0RRRUJDd1VBQTRJQkFRQ1YyT1VDTjNIbApGZUpWNjIyR0pKWUdIYmNiVDZXbjJnK0hxM2E3RG5IOENJdDBpZGlzZVRUVjc2cUJNTHlCcnIxcStZY0Q3cE9pCjlwNTR4cFRvZTVNL0YxdlozUG5IS3FWbEwzTnJNK2U3cW1ZMzR0MmdXYUtmNGNRdTFkMHdlVGRlWnRZUHl3YkoKN1NrNlVQV0RKaFhteVJpR3dXZTFjbFJQTUE1Q1VTc0sxa0JKQk5aL2lRampzdDdldERvcXBBRnMzS1d5YlJCQwpKUWpkeU54Um8yNkVXUGg5TlR1RGVwdDVHV3A5ZTluOGRBR2NGZ0VWdHZmUjlKalRTeCtscDdaMDF6OEdvM1VqCmRnUG16UlllQ1Z6RXFIT2E2Z091OHA3ZEtpck9rbkM2NUI0aE9HUmlFZzg0a0RjSHBQbm5SQWk0OHBPLzlmVFgKQzJsS2padWFnOGZwCi0tLS0tRU5EIENFUlRJRklDQVRFLS0tLS0K
server: https://ED48D01A0135255E7AEA3B6EF6F41B81.gr7.ap-south-1.eks.amazonaws.com
name: arn:aws:eks:ap-south-1:433614228219:cluster/HR-dev-eksdemo1
contexts:
context:
cluster: arn:aws:eks:ap-south-1:433614228219:cluster/HR-dev-eksdemo1
user: arn:aws:eks:ap-south-1:433614228219:cluster/HR-dev-eksdemo1
name: arn:aws:eks:ap-south-1:433614228219:cluster/HR-dev-eksdemo1
current-context: arn:aws:eks:ap-south-1:433614228219:cluster/HR-dev-eksdemo1
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
name: arn:aws:eks:ap-south-1:433614228219:cluster/HR-dev-eksdemo1
user:
exec:
apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta2
args:
- --region
- ap-south-1
- eks
- get-token
- --cluster-name
- HR-dev-eksdemo1
command: aws


To resolve the issue

Open your kubeconfig file (typically located at ~/.kube/config).
Locate the section with the user configuration for your EKS cluster.
Update the apiVersion field under the exec section.

    apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1

to:
    apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1

apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: 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
    server: https://ED48D01A0135255E7AEA3B6EF6F41B81.gr7.ap-south-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:ap-south-1:433614228219:cluster/HR-dev-eksdemo1
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:ap-south-1:433614228219:cluster/HR-dev-eksdemo1
    user: arn:aws:eks:ap-south-1:433614228219:cluster/HR-dev-eksdemo1
  name: arn:aws:eks:ap-south-1:433614228219:cluster/HR-dev-eksdemo1
current-context: arn:aws:eks:ap-south-1:433614228219:cluster/HR-dev-eksdemo1
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:ap-south-1:433614228219:cluster/HR-dev-eksdemo1
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1
      command: aws
      args:
        - --region
        - ap-south-1
        - eks
        - get-token
        - --cluster-name
        - HR-dev-eksdemo1

After making this change, try running the kubectl get nodes command again. This should resolve the apiVersion error.
API Version Guide:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/client-authentication.v1/
